# How do I recover a deleted item from Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I've just deleted a file from Visual Studio 2010. Could someone help me with step-by-step instructions, i.e. press file, then -something-, then recover?

Comment: This got nothing to do with Visual Studio or with this site - here are some [google results relevant for you](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=deleted+files+recovery&pbx=1&oq=deleted+files&aq=1&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=1302l3102l0l4740l13l7l0l4l4l0l232l1298l0.4.3l10l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=d1d5876cfe22f588&biw=1400&bih=941).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

I just added *.cs file to my project and deleted...this file appeared in **Recycle Bin**, so try to find that file there.

Good luck.

Comment: yup , before reading your answer I found it the same place, the Recycle bin :)

Comment: If I could kiss you I would

Comment: I know that it's funny - but it's one of the most useful answers for me :)

Comment: I think it is useful hint for everyone after small heart attack(accidental deletion) :)

Comment: @Reniuz I don't think it helps either for Microsoft Visual Studio to say "'1kHoursOfWorkNotBackedUp.cs' will be deleted **permanently**" when clearly it should instead read, "...will be sent to Recycling Bin [from which it may be recovered so you don't have a heart attack]. Are you sure?"

Comment: @MattBorja Yes I agree :) But if you confirmed the permanent deletion you probably didn't read what was the message and you will try to delete file again to read it...or end up coming here for the answer :)

Comment: After restoring from the Recyle Bin: At the top of Solution Explorer, you'll find a small icon which says "Show All Files" when you hover over it. Click that to see your file in the project again. Then right click the file and select "Include in Project".

Comment: I accidentally deleted the bin folder which was too large to put in the recycle bin so it is "gone".