# Form.cs file is opening in text box with unreadable form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I was working on a desktop app in VS2012. Suudenly there was a power failure, when I restarted the computer and opened mainform.cs file in a textbox I see unreadable data in it. It looks like following.
  ,      $   H   l   H   $     €      D             €ì     $          ¼      ì
   , 
  €    P T D
        Ô  °

Backup was not set and the file is main form for the app. Does anyone have an idea how to recover the file?

Comment: is there a way to recover files in visual studio 2012

Comment: Are you talking about opening the file `mainform.cs` in Visual Studio and your code is all garbled?

Comment: @JeffBridgman Yes. it is all garbage and visual studio is giving errors on this garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Recovering file from the Visual Studio document cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897956/recovering-file-from-the-visual-studio-document-cache), its a different cause but the indicated location might have the backup you need. If not and you don't have any backup or are using some sort of source control i am afraid you'll have to redo all your code.

Comment: i got it by opening properties of the folder and selected previous versions. got a backup from there