# Manual recovery in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

how can I use the backup files in MS visual studio 2010 without relying on the auto recovery feature? Lets say I clicked the "Do Not Recover" button before when the recovery dialog box prompted but now I wanted to recover it. I do have the backup files in the backup folder. How can I load it? thanks!

It is because I noticed that there is a missing codes (methods) in my project after my computer crashed.

Comment: Best way to do it to use source control, So you can always have repository of your source code and files.

Comment: what do you mean to use source control??

Comment: Version Controlling System like Visual Source Safe, SVN, TFS, Mercurial, Git etc. Where you can commit your files to version control and always have backup of that. Manual Recovery is not possible with Visual Studio.

Comment: aww, so the only way for me to use that backup files is when visual studio prompted on the first time? The thing is, damage is already done, I don't have a backup of that method after my pc crashed.

Comment: See this question answer this might help you-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897956/recovering-file-from-the-visual-studio-document-cache