# Recover an older version of the file

Tags: visual-studio

My laptop just shutdown unexpectedly when i am doing my project work on Visual Studio 2010. At that time I was editing a `css` file. After the system was restarted i see that `css` file was corrupted and it has nothing in it.

I was almost completed with my project. Now I am lost at vacuum and I don't know what to do.

**Is there anyway to get my whole code back ?**

The file is 7 KB in size and it shows a large amount of white spaces when opened in Notepad

Comment: according to this VS has a backup folder -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897956/recovering-file-from-the-visual-studio-document-cache

Comment: Already checked it. Unfortunately it is empty :(

Comment: check the auto recover option in VS  -- probably not enabled? -- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/06/30/autorecover/ --

Comment: You didn't save any of your changes? Well, at least you've learned something. To save yourself more learning experiences in the future, you might want to look into source control. Pick your favorite implementation (Git and Mercurial are solid, popular choices) and start learning to use it. Not only will that be a marketable job skill, it'll save your bacon.

Comment: @Tasos it is enabled. But if I am correct, it will take a backup every 5 minutes only if the file was not saved. In my case the file was saved. I was just changing one line to see the result.

Comment: you seem to running out of options then -- Your last option is to install a recovery program to search for deleted files on the hard disk. you may be in luck and find your css file or if by luck the auto recover last saved files -- heres one i used  in the past -- https://www.piriform.com/recuva -- the free version should be ok  -- let me know if you have rescued it

Comment: I will try, I used `ILSpy` as mentioned [here](http://superuser.com/a/440876). But it only shows the CS codes. Can I get other files using `ILSpy` ?