# Visual Studio, Opening file returns unicode numbers

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

When I try to run my Visual Studio project, it only returns numbers. I worked on it for quite a while and i had lots of code. I can still run the game from a previous build, but i am unsure on how to actually access this previous save. I have a picture and any help would be great.[image: Used to be code]

Comment: I'm sorry, but that looks irrecoverable. It's been overwritten with all zeroes, probably when Visual Studio crashed or you lost power. Next time, make backups or use source control.

Comment: Might be worth checking out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897956/recovering-file-from-the-visual-studio-document-cache