# VSCode re-opens every file that was ever not saved in a workspace when folder opened

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open a folder in vscode, any file that was ever not saved before closing vscode is re-opened as unsaved even though it may no longer exist.

1. Open any file of any type in a workspace
2. Modify the file
3. Close VScode without saving the file.
4. Re-open VSCode
5. The original file is loaded as unsaved (good)
6. Save the file, and close it
7. Close VSCode
8. Re-open VSCode
9. **The original file is re-loaded as unsaved again (bad).**

My VSCode session now loads close to 30 files on startup, even though they have all been saved and in some cases deleted. Even my settings.json file loads as unsaved.
[image]

Things I've tried:

1. Closing all files before exiting
2. Closing all files, workspace before exiting
3. Updating every vscode setting I can find relating to file closing and opening at shutdown/startup
4. Uninstalling vscode and reinstalling. Even after this, the same list of 30 files is loaded at workspace open

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does VS Code restore files with their changes that I didn't save before closing the application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56076678/how-does-vs-code-restore-files-with-their-changes-that-i-didnt-save-before-clos)

Comment: what actually is the question here?

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows \users\[user]\Appdata\roaming\Code directory, locate the **storage.json** file, open in editor.

1. Remove all of the entries in the **OpenedPathsList** section
2. Locate the **windowsState.lastActiveWindow.BackupPath** entry
3. Delete **all** of the subdirectories inside this folder name

EDIT This doesn't actually fix the problem - It just removes the symptoms.